# Enable other KexAlgorihtms

Tags: authentication, ssh

I need to authenticate rundeck with any of the following:
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,curve25519-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512

But it seems only the following options are available:
ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Is there a possible way to do that with the opensource version?

Answer (score 0):

From [rundeck/rundeck issue 4349](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4349), apparently not.

An "[OpenSSH Node Execution Plugins](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/openssh.html#openssh-node-execution-plugins)" might be useful as a workaround.

The [other workaround](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4349#issuecomment-630422914) being:

> Use the script exec/copy instead of jsch:
>
> ```sh
> service.FileCopier.default.provider=script-copy
> service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=script-exec
> plugin.script-copy.default.command=scp ${file-copy.file} >${node.username}@${node.hostname}\:${file-copy.destination}
> plugin.script-copy.default.remote-filepath=${node.destdir}/${file-copy.filename}
> plugin.script-exec.default.command=ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >${node.username}@${node.hostname} ${exec.command}
> plugin.script-exec.default.shell=bash -c
> ```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I could not test it yet, but when I have results I will post it here.